# Логика обобщенных классов

Tags: java

Читаю документацию: про обобщеные классы вот код:

```java
class Account<T>
{
    private T _id;
    T getId(){return _id;}
    Account(T id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }
}
 
class DepositAccount extends Account<Integer>{
 
    DepositAccount(){
        super(5);
    }
}
```

при наследовании класса **Account**, который имеет параметр **T** при наследовании мы указали класс(параметр) **Integer**

**А как будет оно работать на наследие и возможно ли наследовать обобщенные классы без параметров?**

Comment: параметизированные типы могут быть определены исключительно ссылочным типом, а все ссылочные типы наследуются от класса Object, посему, если вы не определите дженерик при наследовании, то получите класс, параметизированный  Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наследование обобщённых классов может выполняться следующими способами

- Потомок -- обобщённый класс:

```java
class GenParent<T> {
    T foo;
}
class GenChild<E> extends GenParent<E> {}
```

Класс-потомок предоставляет некий дополнительный *обобщённый* функционал, как и его предок.  То есть у класса `GenChild` указан (несвязанный unbounded) аргумент типа, и компилятор знает, что при использовании такого класса *необходимо* указать конкретный тип.

- Потомок -- конкретный класс

```java
class IntChild extends GenParent<Integer> {}
```

Класс-потомок использует конкретный тип `Integer`, наследуя обобщённый класс.
Здесь поле `foo` (а также соответствующие геттеры/сеттеры/аргументы конструктора и т.д.) приобретает конкретный тип `Integer`, известный компилятору.

- Потомок -- "сырой" (raw) класс

```java
class RawChild extends GenParent {}
```

Не рекомендуемый способ, так как компилятор знает `GenParent` -- обобщённый класс и не может найти требуемый конкретный тип, потому выдаёт предупреждение вида:

> GenParent is a raw type. References to generic type GenParent should be parameterized

В данном случае такое объявление эквивалентно `class RawChild extends GenParent<Object>`, о чем указано в комментарии Дмитрия, поле `foo` становится типа `Object`, и может принимать объекты любого типа, что характерно для *типонебезопасного* кодирования начала 2000-х годов до появления Java 1.5.